# how to rewrite the url in Struts application

Tags: url-rewriting, struts

i'm using Struts 1.3 and Tiles framework,
i have a home page url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/TDS_PRO/
```

later i can click any of my link button..
if i click `insert` link

`http://localhost:8080/TDS_PRO/MainMenu.html?method=Insert` it will insert the data and displays all data as a result page

problem is when i refresh the page previous link is goes to the server and trying to insert same record but in my table `primary constraint` is there so it will generate `Exception` and displaying that `Exception in JSp page`..

if i set `Action` `scope` is `Request` then that link goes to `Action class` and Generating `Null Pointer Exception`

how to solve this problem...???

give some ideas..

Comment: take a look at this link on how to prevent duplicate form resubmit in Struts http://baskervillesd.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/prevent-multiple-form-submits/

Answer (score 0):

**Insert** operations should not be on GET request (simple href link) from page. They should be implemented via **HTTP POST** using a form submit. Then browser will warn the user when he refreshes.

However, you can try `<forward redirect=true>` from Page1 -> page2. I think this should prevent resubmit on page refresh. Also, have a look at **Synchronizer token pattern** discussion http://www.coderanch.com/t/51602/Struts/Duplicate-form-submission-Synchronizer-Token